# How to save changes to XML file using TinyXML?

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, c++builder, tinyxml

I'm working on a project that requires me to load some of the data from an XML file on to a GUI. The GUI allows the user to make some changes to the data. What I want to be able to do is to save these changes back onto the XML file.

I know it is possible to rewrite the whole file but the file is pretty huge, and not all the data in the file is being changed or even being used in my program.

This is my first project working with TinyXML and C++ Builder. I am just looking for some suggestions as to how I should approach this.

Comment: The TinyXML [tutorial](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html) would be a nice start off point for using the library itself. This is just tangential to the question, but AFAIK, TinyXML is a DOM parser. If you only need to deal with parts of the XML file, a SAX parser would be faster.

Comment: i just quickly googled SAX parser to see what it was about and it seems like it could work. would u have any suggestion for an open source one?

Comment: Quick trip to Google lead me to the [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) parser. It supports both DOM and SAX. Google also returned [this](http://lars.ruoff.free.fr/xmlcpp/) list of C/C++ parsing libraries, perhaps it would be useful as reference.

Comment: thanks will look deeper into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are certain that the new text will be exactly the same size as the old, rewriting only part of a text file is not a good idea in general. There are file formats where piecemeal replacement is possible. XML is not one of them. Not in the general case, at least.

Inserting data in the middle of a file, thus moving the rest down, is basically equivalent to loading the rest of the file, making the file bigger, and writing it back. So you may as well just load the entire file, make your modifications, and save it again. Your code will be simpler and likely not much slower.

And no, a SAX parser isn't going to help you here. It allows you to stream reading (though I would suggest a pull parser rather than a push one), but that's not going to allow you to insert data into the file. That's generally not supported by most XML parsers I know of. They can *write* data, but writing and non-destructively inserting are two different things.

Comment: i think ur advice makes the most sense so far. like i said in response to sad's answer, i need to make sure the method in which i'm choosing to save the xml, will not damage other parts of the file that was not used for my program. and by moving those other parts of the file down or up or w.e, it seems the least chance of damaging the data it holds. thanks

Comment: @livelaughlove: Making changes to XML data without a program that actually understands the XML format is always more dangerous than using a program that does understand XML. TinyXML (or any XML parser) will ensure that you're writing XML; some non-XML insertion tool won't. And all it takes is a single close tag in the wrong place to screw up an XML file's formatting entirely.

Comment: i'm not too worry about the actual format of the xml. my concern is (and forgive me if this seems completely silly, still new to this tinyxml and xml stuff) whether there would be a chance of say the changed data overiding other parts of the XML file or changing the data of other parts of the XML file itself. from my understanding of ur explanation, i am basically just shifting other parts of the xml as a whole and making room for the changed data, but not really changing the data in the other parts.

Answer (score 2):

TinyXml will let you do what you want without damaging the file contents (as long as its valid xml). I just checked this so I am quite certain. Obviously you have to know and precisely what attributes and tags you want to edit, but you can add/edit tags without affecting existing attributes/tags/comments even within the tags you edit. It will take a while until you get used to the structure, but it is definitely possible.

You have to know the structure of the xml!

```
TiXmlDocument doc("filepath"); //will open your document

if (!doc.LoadFile()) //you do have to open the whole file
{
    cout<<"No XML structure found"<<endl;
    return; // exit function don't load anything
}
TiXmlElement *root = doc.RootElement(); //pointer to root element
```

Now you can use this pointer and commands like:

```
root->FirstChild("tageone")->ToElement();
tageone->SetDoubleAttribute("attribute", value);
```

to change stuff.

Sorry for the rushed explanation, but you'll need to read through the documentation a bit to get the hang of it.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

### Update

As I said in the comment, I don't think that you are better off if you insert into the middle of a file. However, if you need/want additional security I suggest two additional steps:

- perform a sanity check of the xml file at all the important steps. This can be anything where you make sure that the file you are reading is really what you need.
- calculate a checksum over the content of the whole file before saving and check it afterwards. This does not necessarily need to be a CRC, I just named the function `calculate_crc()`. Anything that lets you verify the integrity of the data is good.

I would do this approximately as follows (pseudocode):

```
TiXmlDocument doc( "demo.xml" );
doc.LoadFile();

perform_sanitycheck(doc);

//  do whatever you need to change

perform_sanitycheck(doc);
unsigned int crc = calculate_crc(doc);

doc.SaveFile("temp_name.xml");  // save the file under another name

TiXmlDocument doc2( "temp_name.xml" );
perform_sanitycheck(doc2);
if(verify_crc(doc, crc))
{
    delete_file("demo.xml");
    rename_file("temp_name.xml", "demo.xml");
}
```

The sanity check would take the appropriate action if necessary. You need to substitute the two function `delete_file()` and `rename_file()` with an API or library function for your environment.

The functions `calculate_crc()` and `verify_crc()` could be specifically crafted to check only the parts that you need to have unchanged.

Comment: it's not really the file size that's a problem. the xml file holds alot of important information. i am using only a part of the file for my program and only making changes to that part. so if i were to use SaveFile would it have even a slight chance of damaging the other parts of the xml file at all?